# Java Classpath error-cannot find my class

Tags: java, classpath, randoop

I am trying to use randoop(automatic test generator for Java) and randoop cannot find my class:

```
eliezer@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ java -ea -classpath \
 randoop.1.3.2.jar:home/eliezer/myclasses \
 randoop.main.Main gentests \
 --testclass=/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses/ArrayListError

policy = sun.security.provider.PolicyFile@85af80
Throwable thrown while handling command:java.lang.Error:\
classForName(/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses/ArrayListError)
java.lang.Error: classForName(/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses/ArrayListError)
at randoop.util.Reflection.classForName(Reflection.java:206)
at randoop.util.Reflection.loadClassesFromList(Reflection.java:386)
at randoop.main.GenInputsAbstract.findClassesFromArgs(GenInputsAbstract.java:507)
at randoop.main.GenTests.handle(GenTests.java:184)
at randoop.main.Main.nonStaticMain(Main.java:80)
at randoop.main.Main.main(Main.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: \
 /home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses/ArrayListError
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at randoop.util.Reflection.classForName(Reflection.java:198)
... 5 more
Randoop failed.
Last sequence under execution:null
```

My class is called ArrayListError.java and is found in `/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses`.

The randoop docs are found at: [https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/index.html](http://randoop.googlecode.com/hg/doc/index.html).

I am sure it is something really trivial but I'm inexperienced with these things.

Comment: `home.eliezer.Desktop.myclasses` is your package or directory structure?

Comment: @Rp its a directory structure-I am only testing a single class and it is in /home/eliezer/myclasses and its name is ArrayListError.java

Comment: then you need to set classpath to `home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses` ('Desktop' is missing in your classpath) and you need to call `classForName("ArrayListError");`

Comment: @Rp I have done that now-still the error.
How and where do I call classForName("ArrayListError") Thanks

Comment: Try `java -ea -classpath randoop.1.3.2.jar:/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=ArrayListError`

Comment: Posted the comment as answer :-)

Comment: @Rp- sorry that I did not see your comment before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set your classpath such that, jvm should be able to locate all your resources like classes, files, jars etc.
In your case, `ArrayListError` is placed under directory `/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses`. You need to place this in your classpath.
Once you point your classpath to mentioned directory, You need to pass the class name to `--testclass=ArrayListError`.

`java -ea -classpath randoop.1.3.2.jar:/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=ArrayListError`

should fix your problem. I suggest you to search on setting classpath and read on.

Comment: Mention in your response the change to --testclass - that's very relevant.  Nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

> my class is called ArrayListError.java and is found in
>   /home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses.

Your ArrayListError.java is the source code, but java virtual machine needs a compiled class in its classpath.

EDIT:
Since you said that you have the .class file also, then your problem can be solved in two ways

a. No package

Run the command (take care of the --testclas, it is not directory, it should be the class)

> java -ea -classpath randoop.1.3.2.jar:/home/eliezer/myclasses 
>   randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=ArrayListError

b. Class in a package

If your ArrayListError does have `package com.test;` make a directory /com/test in your **myclasses** directory and run the command below

> java -ea -classpath
>   randoop.1.3.2.jar:/home/eliezer/myclasses/com/test/ randoop.main.Main 
>   gentests --testclass=com.test.ArrayListError

Comment: I don't think I need to create a jar file

Comment: You don't need to create the jar, as long as the directory at the root of the *compiled* package hierarchy is on your classpath.

Comment: That is also in /home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath on the command line;
I see `home/eliezer/myclasses`, without the leading `/`.

Comment: And you added Desktop into the path?  It's all a bit confusing at this point.

Comment: eliezer@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ java -ea -classpath randoop.1.3.2.jar:/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=/home/eliezer/Desktop/myclasses/ArrayListError