# Java Class Path issue with Randoop

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, classpath, randoop

I'm using Randoop, the automatic test generator for Java.

However, when running Randoop from the commandline, I can't seem to figure out how to properly specify the classpath.

I read through this question: [Java Classpath error-cannot find my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760484/java-classpath-error-cannot-find-my-class) in detail but my setup seems a bit different.

I'm running on a Windows machine.

The overall project structure looks like this:

```
cse331/
    bin/
        hw5/
            GraphNode.class
    src/
        hw5/
            GraphNode.java
    randoop-2.1.4.jar
```

(There are some other files but the not important here, I think)

I tried calling:

```
java -ea -classpath randoop-2.1.4.jar:bin/* randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=GraphNode --timelimit=20
```

But received the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class randoop.main.Main
```

I've tried several variations, loading in the .java file instead of the .class file for the classpath but no option has worked so far. If I don't specify the class path at the end of randoop-2.1.4, I get an error message saying the class GraphNode cannot be found.

The setup is just the first step and I can't seem to get on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the solution was to remove the asterisk from bin/ and include the semi colon like Sumit suggested.

```
java -ea -classpath randoop-2.1.4.jar;bin/ randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=GraphNode --timelimit=20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: It will surely remove this error.
java -cp cse331/bin;randoop-2.1.4.jar randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass=hw5.GraphNode --timelimit=100.

If your project is maven project, Try to include all dependencies. for downloading use this command: mvn dependency:copy-dependencies

Let me know if you have any other queries regarding randoop.